# How to solve this with the D = rt formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck with this question. 
I don't know how to get the distance with these two point of information

D = 20 * t

D = 12 * t

70 = r * 4.5

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Tzj.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the third equation you assumed a single value of $r$ in 
$$ 70= 45*r, $$ 
However, $r$ is *changing*.

You have two speeds from two durations and two travelled distances, which have to be solved separately. A graph may be an aid to see changing speed as changing slope.

Distance y-axis is shown scaled by a factor 10.

$(xm,tm)$ are distance and time for the instant that she started to slow down.

$$ \dfrac{xm}{tm}= 20 ; \quad \dfrac{70-xm}{4.5-tm}= 12 ; $$

[image]

Solving the simultaneous equation for the two variables we get solution:

$$ xm=40 \,miles , tm= 2\, hours. $$